# Aligning Figures with captions

Tags: html, css, alignment, figure, caption

I am making a quick website and I want to have images with one caption underneath each image which are going to contain the price of each item in the image. I have put a caption underneath each image however I want them to be vertically aligned but currently they are horizontally aligned. Can anybody help me please?

I have attached my HTML and CSS code below.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sqPD3/)

HTML CODE

```
<div class="wrapper">

<div class="top">
    <!--Background set in CSS-->
</div><!--  end of top-->

<div class="menu">
        <h1>Rosy's Jewellery</h1>                   
        <ul id="nav">       
        <li><a href="index.html">Home           </a></li>
        <li><a href="Bracelets.html">Jewellery  </a></li>
        <li><a href="Locations.html">Locations  </a></li>
        <li><a href="ContactUs.html">Contact Us </a></li>
        <li><a href="Reviews.html">Reviews      </a></li>
        </ul>       
</div>
<!-- end of menu -->


  <div class="main2">
    <H1>Jewellery</H1>
        <ul id="nav2">
        <li><a href="Bracelets.html">Bracelets  </a></li>
        <li><a href="Necklaces.html">Necklaces </a></li>
        <li><a href="Earrings.html">Earrings </a></li>
        </ul>
            <div class ="figures">

                <FIGURE>
                <img src="Images/Jewellery2.png">
                <FIGCAPTION>Jewellery.</FIGCAPTION>
                </FIGURE>

                <FIGURE>
                <img src="Images/Jewellery3.png">
                <FIGCAPTION>Jewellery.</FIGCAPTION>
                </FIGURE>

                <FIGURE>
                <img src="Images/Jewellery4.png">
                <FIGCAPTION>Jewellery.</FIGCAPTION>
                </FIGURE>

                <FIGURE>
                <img src="Images/Jewellery1.png">
                <FIGCAPTION>Jewellery.</FIGCAPTION>
                </FIGURE>

                <FIGURE>
                <img src="Images/Jewellery5.png">
                <FIGCAPTION>Jewellery.</FIGCAPTION>
                </FIGURE>

                <FIGURE>
                <img src="Images/Jewellery9.png">
                <FIGCAPTION>Jewellery.</FIGCAPTION>
                </FIGURE>

                <FIGURE>
                <img src="Images/Jewellery7.png">
                <FIGCAPTION>Jewellery.</FIGCAPTION>
                </FIGURE>

                <FIGURE>
                <img src="Images/Jewellery8.png">
                <FIGCAPTION>Jewellery.</FIGCAPTION>
                </FIGURE>

                <FIGURE>
                <img src="Images/Jewellery6.png">
                <FIGCAPTION>Jewellery.</FIGCAPTION>
                </FIGURE>

                 </div>         
</div>
<!--close main-->



<div class="footer">
    <ul id="footer">
        <li> <img src="Images/facebook.png" /> 
        <img src="Images/twitter.png" />  </li>
        <li> Twitter</li>
        <li> Address </li>      
        <li> Tel</li>
    </ul>
</div> 
<!--end of footer--> 
</div>
```

CSS CODE

```
.wrapper        {
            margin:0 auto;
            background-color:#D1CED4;   ;
            }   

.top            {
            background-color:#000000;
            padding-bottom:2.5em;
            }

.menu           {
            background-color:#FFFFFF;
            border-bottom-width:3px;
            border-bottom-color:#000000;
            border-bottom-style: solid;
            position: relative;
            top:-15px;
            text-align:center;
            font-family:Andalus;
            font-size:16px;
            padding-left:1em;
            padding-right:1em;
            overflow:hidden;
            }

.menu h1        {
            float:left;
            color:#999966;
            font-family:andalus;
            font-size:24;
            }


.main           {
            width:65%;
            margin:0 auto;
            background-color:#FFFFFF;
            text-align:center;
            font-family:andalus;
            font-size:16px;
            padding-top:1em;
            padding-bottom:1em;
            height:100%;
            }


.main img       {
            margin:2.2em;
            }               


.main h1        {
            font-size:20px;
            font-family:andalus;
            }

.main2          {
            width:65%;
            margin:0 auto;
            background-color:#FFFFFF;
            text-align:center;
            font-family:andalus;
            font-size:16px;
            padding-top:1em;
            padding-bottom:1em;
            height:100%;
            }           


.main2 h1       {
            font-size:20px;
            font-family:andalus;
            }

.figures            {
            display:inline;
            }


        {   float: left;
            }


.footer         {
            text-align:centre;
            background-color:#C8C8C8;
            color:#000000;
            font-family:andalus;
            }

#footer li      {
            display:inline-block;
            padding-right:6em;
            vertical-align:middle;
            margin-top:-0.5em;
            }


#footer img     {
            margin:1em;
            }


#nav            {
            padding-top:1em;
            }


#nav a          {
            text-decoration:none;
            }   

#nav a:link     {
            color:black;
            }

#nav a:visited      {
            color:black;
            }

#nav a:hover        {
            color:black;
            }


#nav ul         {
            display:inline-block;
            }


#nav li         {
            display:inline-block;
            margin-right:4em;
            padding-right:3em;
            }

#nav2           {
            padding-top:1.5em;
            }

#nav2 a         {
            text-decoration:none;
            }   

#nav2 a:link    {   
            color:black;
            }

#nav2 a:visited {
            color:black;
            }

#nav2 a:hover           {
            color:black;
            }


#nav2 ul            {
            display:inline-block;
            }


#nav2 li            {
            display:inline-block;
            margin-right:2em;
            padding-right:3em;
            }


.left           {
            width:28%;
            float:left;
            }

.right          {
            width:28%;
            float:right;
            }

form            {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 400px;
            padding: 1em;
            border: 1px solid #CCC;
            border-radius: 1em;
            margin-top: 2em;
            }

label           { 
            display: inline-block;
            width: 90px;
            text-align: right;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add:

```css
.figures figure {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/sqPD3/7/).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
figure img {
       display:inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;

            }
figure figcaption {
           display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/sqPD3/5/)

Comment: This isn't what the question asks for. However as some advice there's no point repeating identical CSS declarations, you should just use two selectors separated with a comma: `figure img, figure figcaption { ... }`

Comment: "I have put a caption underneath each image however I want them to be vertically aligned but currently they are horizontally aligned." The question is vague. I read that the **image and caption** should be v-aligned...not the figures.